# Help with the step II in the proof of Riesz Representation Theorem in big Rudin

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, riesz-representation-theorem

In Riesz Representation Theorem, $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, and $\Lambda$ is a positive linear functional on $C_c(X)$ which is the set of all continuous functions on $X$ with compact support. One conclusion of the theorem is that $\mu(K) < \infty$ for all compact set $K$.

This conclusion is proved in step II (page 43, Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*, third edition). In Rudin's proof, he let $K \prec f$ ($f$ belongs to $C_c(X)$, take value $1$ on $K$, and $0 \leq f \leq 1$), then deduce $\mu(K) \leq \Lambda f$ and assert $\mu(K) < \infty$.

What I don't understand is that can assert $\mu(K) < \infty$ just from $\mu(K) \leq \Lambda f$? Can $\Lambda f$ be infinite?

Comment: So he did: he first proved $\mu(K)\le\cdots\le \Lambda(2f)$, then, since $\Lambda f<\infty$, concluded that $\mu(K)\le \Lambda(2f)<\infty$.

Comment: I don't understand why Λf<∞. Can it be ∞?

Answer (score 3):

Please see the exact words below  from Rudin.

[image]

Since $f\in C_c(X)$ and it is continuous, it is easy to see that $f(X)$ is finite. So, as a result, $\Lambda f$ has to be finite.

Comment: So it can be regarded as a part of definition of the linear functional Λ?

Comment: In the last step why did he put the absolute value of $a$ ? Is not it sufficient to assume $f$ is positive?

Answer (score 0):

$\Lambda$ is a (positive) linear functional on $C_c(X)$, so it is a linear map from $C_c(X)$ to $\mathbb{C}$. In particular, $\Lambda(f) \neq \infty$ for any $f \in C_c(X)$, since $\infty \not\in \mathbb{C}$.

The other answer by @Yuhang gives the meaning of the adjective "positive" used here to describe $\Lambda$. However, that is unnecessary to know why $\Lambda(f) \neq \infty$.